# how to parse an oracle DDL script?

Tags: script, metadata, oracle-12c, oracle-database

My problem is that I need to key in details of a list of DDL script into my metadata table but due to the size of the file, it is difficult to do it one by one.

I would like to check is there any way that program parses a DDL script? I am able to write a program by C# or NodeJS. Any logic suggestion? I need to identify Table name, column, their type and size if there is any. it should understand Alter script and create the script. It should ignore create synonyms and grant scripts.

what is your suggestion? The format of DDL file is as below:

```
ALTER TABLE GNMT_POLICY ADD V_TPA_COMP_BRANCH   VARCHAR2(30);
/

CREATE TABLE TEMP_TEMPLATE_MASTER
(
N_TEST_ID       NUMBER  PRIMARY KEY ,
V_TEST_DESC     VARCHAR2(100) NOT NULL,
V_TEMPLATE_PURPOSE  VARCHAR2(1),
V_PLAN_CODE         VARCHAR2(10) NOT NULL,
D_ACTIVE_FROM       DATE,
D_ACTIVE_TO         DATE,
N_TEMPLATE_TYPE     NUMBER,
N_FIXED_COLUMN_LENGTH NUMBER,
V_DELIMITER         VARCHAR2(1),
N_START_ROW         NUMBER,
D_LASTUPD_INFTIM    DATE
);
/
CREATE OR REPLACE PUBLIC SYNONYM TEMP_TEMPLATE_MASTERFOR TEMP_TEMPLATE_MASTER;
/
GRANT ALL ON TEMP_TEMPLATE_MASTER TO RFORALLOBJECTS;
/
CREATE TABLE TEMPLATE_DETAIL
(
N_TEMPLATE_ID               NUMBER CONSTRAINT Fk_temp_gnmt_temp references mplate_Master(n_Template_ID),
V_PROP_REC_SEQ_NO           VARCHAR2(25) NOT NULL,
V_LASTUPD_USER              VARCHAR2(100) NOT NULL,
TABLE_NAME                  VARCHAR2(30),
N_SEQ_NO                    NUMBER
);
/
CREATE OR REPLACE PUBLIC SYNONYM TEMPLATE_DETAIL FOR TEMPLATE_DETAIL;
/
GRANT ALL ON TEMPLATE_DETAILTO RFORALLOBJECTS;
```

**Edit 1:** based on Seth comment I found a useful link in youtube that shows how DDL is working in Oracle DB.  [Link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bCWljD74yr4). In the video said a DDL is a DML with auto-commit.

Comment: SQL is a well defined format. Actually Oracle does the parsing. Why not just write a query that returns the data you need?

Comment: @seth: what do you mean by write a query that returns the data? In my organization developers need to keep track of their changes in meta data dictionary base on the customer and issue they solve. When we have a big change in the system they are not willing to fill the schema chenges, therefore i thought of writing a piece of code to help them.  Regarding your idea, is there any way to use oracle parser? For instance give query as parameter and it parse it?

Comment: It's what inherently happens if you run a DDL statement against the DB. As for what I mean, write a query that gets the list of tables and their properties in the form you need. That does mean you will have to run the statement first. If in doubt run it on a test database that's clean and export your data afterwards.

Comment: @Seth, can you post your answer with a small example? your solution was a really smart solution. However, I think if u post your answer with an example I can digest it better

Comment: @Seth: do think Oracle Flashback can help me? but what if my database be on 6i database? I think flashback is available from 10g.

Comment: [Check this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/452464/how-can-i-get-column-names-from-a-table-in-oracle) which is what I had in mind. This doesn't really have anything to do with Flashback.

Comment: @Seth: aha, I got you. well, I want to have the list of changes before running the query.

Comment: Which is why I suggested running it on a test database. Use it on the test/temporary database, get that data you need, delete the database. The alternative would be to just run grep or similar with a regular expression and "fine tune" your data afterwards.